# React-Admin retrieve item on AutocompleteInput onSelect

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

I've got the following code in React-Admin v3

```
          <AutocompleteInput
            onSelect={(value) => {
              setCurrentCategory({ reference: value.id });
            }}
```

After upgrading to v4 now the AutocompleteInput uses MUI not downshift, as described in https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Upgrade.html#autocompleteinput-and-autocompletearrayinput-now-use-mui-autocomplete

So the code above breaks with the error:
`Property 'id' does not exist on type 'SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement, Event>'.`

How can I get the selectedItem again as per [onSelect on downshift](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift#onselect) but using React-Admin v4 with MUI?

Answer (score 0):

React-admin's `AutocompleteInput` uses MUI's `<Autocomplete>`, which exposes an `onChange` function for that.

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#props

Since you're overriding the core functionality of React-admin's `AutocompleteInput`, I suggest you use MUI's `<Autocomplete>` directly.

Comment: I've changed the code to:
onChange={(_event, value) => {
              setCurrentCategory({ reference: value.id });
            }}
PS: but does not seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to

```
          <AutocompleteInput
            onChange={(value_id) => {
              setCurrentCategory({ reference: value_id });
            }}
(...)
            choices={mainCategories}
            optionText="name"
            optionValue="id"
```